# Using Kibana4 Tile Map with Geo-Points

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana-4, geohashing

I'm using Logstash to insert a `location` attribute into my logs that are going into ElasticSearch:

```
"location" : {
  "lat":31.07,
  "lon":-82.09
}
```

I'm then setting up a mapping to tell ElasticSearch it's a [Geo-Point](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/geopoints.html).  I'm not exactly sure how this call should look.  This is what I've been using so far:

```
PUT logstash-*/_mapping/latlon
{
  "latlon" : {
    "properties" : {
      "location" : {
        "type" : "geo_point",
        "lat_lon" : true,
        "geohash" : true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I query for matching records in Kibana 4, the `location` field is annotated with a small globe. So far, so good.

When I move to the Tile Map visualization, bring up matching records, bucket by Geo Coordinates, select `Geohash` from the 'Aggregation' drop down, and then select `location` from the `Field` drop down, and press 'Apply', no results are returned.

The aggreations part of the request looks like this:

```
"aggs": {
    "2": {
      "geohash_grid": {
        "field": "location",
        "precision": 3
      }
    }
  }
```

And the response:

```
{
  "took": 5,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 10,
    "successful": 10,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 689,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "2": {
      "buckets": []
    }
  }
}
```

For some reason, ElasticSearch isn't returning results, even though it seems like the Geo-Point mapping is recognized.  Any tips for how to troubleshoot from here?

Comment: Having the same problem... Did you find a solution for this ?

Comment: No, still no solution.  I've tried upgrading ElasticSearch (currently on 1.6.0, thinking of moving now to 1.7), but I haven't yet upgraded to the very latest Kibana 4.  I'll probably try that next and report back.